# Intelligent Text Labels for Line Plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since my data is being updated daily, I would like to add "intelligent" text labels that do not overlap with lines or text. Is there a package for such issues? How would you address the issue? Personally, I would prefer solutions that work with ggplot2.

At the moment, I solve the labeling as given below with the disadvantage that I have to check and correct the geom_text x and y of quite an amount of plots every time I update my data. I know that a legend would be much easier in this case, but I need to stick to a certain layout.

A small reproducible example:

```
date <- c(1:10)
var1 <- c(4, 4.5, 4.7, 4, 3.5 ,5.5 ,6 ,5 ,5.2, 7.1)
var2 <- c(6, 7.5, 7.7, 5, 5.5 ,7.5 ,9 ,8 ,7.2, 5.1)
data <- data.frame(date, var1, var2)
data$date <- as.Date(data$date)

ggplot(data, aes(date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = var1, colour="y1"),size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = var2, colour="y2"),size=1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#00669C", "#FFC000")) +
  labs(x = "last 10 days", y = NULL, title = "mytitle") +
  guides(color="none") +
  geom_text(aes(as.Date("1970-01-09"), 4), label="Text 1", color="#00669C", size=8) +
  geom_text(aes(as.Date("1970-01-03"), 8.5), label="Text 2", color="#FFC000", size=8) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check the `directlabels` package [link](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org)

Comment: no, I sometimes have three or four lines as well @bunk

Comment: thanks I will have a look at the directlabels @drmariod

Comment: how many labels per/line etc?  `directlabels` is really good, your data needs to be put into long format.  There is also `plotrix::spread.labels`, but it isn't for ggplot

Comment: If you have more lines it would be better to simply use a legend.

Comment: as stated above, "I know that a legend would be much easier in this case, but I need to stick to a certain layout." @Roland